# Regarding my Android app being decomissioned

Tags: android

I had developed an application 4 months back and it has been downloaded by nearly 13000 users already. But Google has decommissioned my app a couple of weeks ago stating that we had performed SEO on the product description, which we haven't. I have been trying to reach Google regarding the same issue but in vain.

Please share your experience with this.